# ShaderToy to PIXI js Filter

Tags: javascript, canvas, shader, webgl, pixi.js

I found this amazing effect on ShaderToy and I want to use it as a filter mask in PIXI. 
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlcGWH

Currently I'm stuck with converting it and I don't see any way out so I hope someone could help with some example or advice. This project is very important to me. I'm still beginner with WebGl, but willing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example here https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/iITifzG1lQqrpvf5wQfGK, it come from https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v5-Hacks#shaders.

Note that you cannot use `#version 300 es` that shadertoy use in pixi.js for now, as they append other stuff at top of the fragment shader code. That mean no array. Note that shadertoy also do the same, and provide some helpers functions, if you check the source code of the website, and make a quick search for `#version 300 es`, you will find what they append at top of the shader (well, actually just a part of it).

Know that `fragColor` become `gl_FragColor`. And that you need a `main()` function.

You might wanna check this page: https://www.shadertoy.com/howto
and this website https://thebookofshaders.com.

Also, if you want to use `#version 300 es`, either go with three.js or another framework, or pull request pixi.js.